# How do I select the comment on a Postgres stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, stored-procedures, comments

Suppose I have a procedure, call it `my_procedure`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE my_procedure(X INT);
```

Then I write:

```
COMMENT ON my_procedure IS 'My comment'
```

How do I then use a `SELECT` statement to retrieve that comment?

This looks promising:

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_description
WHERE objoid = WHAT_SHOULD_THIS_BE?;
```

but I have no idea how to find the `objoid` of `my_procedure`.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SELECT pg_catalog.obj_description(p.oid, 'pg_proc') as "comment"
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc AS p
  WHERE p.proname = 'my_procedure';
```

You may want to also check the values in the pronamespace and proargtypes and prokind columns if there's a chance of multiple procedures or functions having the same name

I got this information by using `psql -E` and looking at the queries it made.